# Could anyone please provode me settings for Custom FFF for Zonestar Z6FB printer

Tags: ultimaker-cura

Recently I bought a printer and failed to find Cura 4.8 settings for it (both in application both myself). My printer Zonestar Z6FB

Currently I doubt in:

1. G-code flavor
2. All printhead settings excluding extruder number (which is obviously 1 in my case)
3. Start/End G-code

[image]

Add printer image to eye trap someone who also interested

[image]

Comment: Your printer looks like a clone of the Creality Ender 2. Have you tried using a printer definition for the Ender 2?

Comment: @Mick believe me it is not a clone. It is the cheapest device you can imagine.

Comment: Well... it is very similar to the Ender 2, and also the Tronxy X2. Both are cantilever printers. I have a Tronxy X1 -- also a cantilever printer but no heated bed. I suspect that settings for either the Ender 2 or the Tronxy X2 will also work with Zonestar Z6. Of the two printers, Cura is more likely to have definitions for the Ender 2.

Comment: I've just checked. Cura does have a definition for the Ender 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some pain, I figured out that if you are a poor Ubuntu/Linux user you should only use the AppImage version of Cura which you can download from [official website](https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-cura)

Next, make the file you downloaded executable `chmod +x *.AppImage`

Next, start it from terminal or by clicking in navigator

Ok, proceed as is and then **Help** ▶ **Show Configuration Folder**.

It will show 2 folders we need `~/.local/share/cura/4.8`

Ok now download `ZONESTAR_Cura_Resources.zip` from [here](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DZIXy4UQyoP1BxjLstUD).

Then copy all files from ZONESTAR_Cura_Resources TO `~/.local/share/cura/4.8` but remember that directory structure is messed up but can be figured out.